# How best to adapt to type changes in Cabal library without CPP?

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal, flycheck

I want to enhance [flycheck-haskell](https://github/flycheck/flycheck-haskell)'s support for auto-configuring flycheck from your .cabal file.

To do this autoconfiguration, flycheck uses [a helper file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flycheck/flycheck-haskell/master/get-cabal-configuration.hs) whose original strategy was to read the .cabal file and use `flattenPackageDescription`.  This was simple, but does not respect conditional expressions, which can cause problems with, e.g. not needing `bytestring-builder` when using newer version of the `bytestring` package.

The appropriate interface to use would seem to be `finalizePackageDescription`.  This does work...but its type signature changed between 1.20 and 1.22---now, instead of taking a `CompilerId`, it now takes a `CompilerInfo`.  Yet I would like to provide consistent support across this API change.

While the solution for this is generally to use `CPP` macros, those macros are provided by `Cabal` itself, and `flycheck` is simply invoking the helper file with `runhaskell`, so we don't have access to them.

The only option I can think of would be to create *another* helper to first get the `Cabal` version information, and then construct appropriate `CPP` settings for our `runhaskell` invocation so we can do things that way.  That should work, but seems like a hack.

So I'm here looking for other options that would allow me to support both versions of the interface, without having to resort to `CPP`.

The code in question is a call to `Distribution.PackageDescription.Configuration.finalizePackageDescription`, like so:

```
case finalizePackageDescription [] (const True) buildPlatform buildCompilerId [] genericDesc' of
  Left e -> putStrLn $ "Issue with package configuration\n" ++ show e
  Right (pkgDesc, _) -> print (dumpPackageDescription pkgDesc cabalFile)
```

The problem is that the fourth parameter, `buildCompilerId` changed type from `CompilerId` to `CompilerInfo`.

What I have implemented---though I would be happy to consider a more self-contained option---is a helper that spits out `-DuseCompilerInfo` (as an s-expr, since we're dealing with Emacs) if it's a sufficiently recent version of Cabal:

```
import Data.Version (Version (Version))
import Distribution.Simple.Utils (cabalVersion)

main :: IO ()
main =
  putStrLn $ if cabalVersion >= Version [1,22] []
             then "(\"-DuseCompilerInfo\")"
             else "()"
```

The original helper is then run with the flag, and conditionally imports the new structures, as well as having the following conditional code just before the case statement above:

```
#ifdef useCompilerInfo
      buildCompilerId = unknownCompilerInfo (CompilerId buildCompilerFlavor compilerVersion) NoAbiTag
#else
      buildCompilerId = CompilerId buildCompilerFlavor compilerVersion
#endif
```

It's not beautiful, but it works.

Comment: I've been told that some of these tricks work http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/06/evil-conditional-compile

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.Unfortunately, I have come to believe the fact that they introduced a new data type (CompilerInfo) makes this infeasible.

Comment: It would be really ugly, but you should always be able to use the Template Haskell approach by constructing the Names that you need with `mkName`. Whether the other approaches mentioned in that blog post would work probably depends on exactly what the two versions of the code you need to write are; maybe include them in your question?